# security kit module settings are blocking own site jQuery calls

Tags: 7, javascript, ajax

I am using Security kit module to enhance security for my website. In that I have enabled `Enable JavaScript + CSS + Noscript protection`  option. This setting is blocking one of Jquery call that is `.load` functionality. The description of this option is here:

> Enable protection via JavaScript, CSS and Noscript tag. This is the most efficient Clickjacking prevention technique. If webiste is not being framed, seckit.document_write.js starts commenting with document.write() and stops when reaches stop SecKit protection. Thus seckit.no_body.css, which sets body display to none, is ignored. If particularly this JavaScript file is being blocked (with XSS filter of Internet Explorer 8 or Safari), seckit.no_body.css sets display: none to body. If JavaScript is disabled within browser, it shows a special message.

This is the JavaScript code.

```javascript
$("[name='dest-target']").click(function(e){
  jQuery("#test_file_download").load(Drupal.settings.basePath + Drupal.settings.pathPrefix + "node/hit/ajax", {'path': filenodeurl});
  return false;
});
```

Please suggest me any alternatives I can use for this.

Answer (score 0):

If this code inline, then try with this:

'unsafe-inline'

Allows the use of inline resources, such as inline  elements, javascript: URLs, inline event handlers, and inline  elements. You must include the single quotes.

'unsafe-eval'

Allows the use of eval() and similar methods for creating code from strings. You must include the single quotes.

Howewer, the proper way to set up this module you can find  [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src).